# Is there a way to loop through html table using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an existing dynamic HTML table named ['taskTable'] and I am trying to loop through each rows and cells than save each data for future use using PHP. I am new in PHP so I apologized if my explanation might be so broad.

I searched the internet to look for identical situation but I can't find exactly same scenario

```
<div class="row uniform">
    <div class="6u$ 12u$(medium)">
        <table id="taskTable" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>SCENARIO</th>
                <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
                <th>COMMAND</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row uniform">
    <div class="6u$ 12u$(medium)">
```

My goal is to loop thru each rows and cells and saved it in a variable for future reference. Please be inform that this table is dynamic I can add row by clicking a button.

Comment: You can do it using javascript

Comment: @PaoloMossini thank you for responding, May I know how to do it in JavaScript?

Comment: You can save rows or cells using `document.getElementsByTagName('tr')` or  `document.getElementsByTagName('td')`